# Get only the element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to get the following code to work, but it always changes the class to all `.tog-faq` divs I have, and i can't get the `$(this)` working.
I've tried using `.toggle();` and `.toggleClass()` in thousands of ways, and it doesn't work. Is there something to do with haml or rails?

A part of the view:

```
- @topics.each do |topic|
.title.col-md-4.white-font
  .red-back
    %h3.white-font= topic.name
    %button{class: 'btn btn-sh-grey', id: 'link-panel', onclick: 'ToggleFaq()'}
      %span.faq-tog Show
  %div.panel-sub.tog-faq.invisible
    -if faq_questions(topic).present?
      - faq_questions(topic).each do |question|
        .faq-con
          %h4.panel.panel-heading.item-name.dark-grey= question.questions
```

current jquery code:

```
function ToggleFaq() { 
 $('.tog-faq').not(this).addClass('invisible');
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
}
```

css

```
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Any help will be great!!

Comment: What code? Please post it!

Comment: `this` wont work when you are just calling a function. The function won't know what element is called unless you pass it in as a parameter. Try looking at this https://api.jquery.com/click/ .

Comment: hmm I think i got it... but then, how can I get the `this` from `.tog-faq` without setting as first parameter? Because i can't click the div if it's `display: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` is not referencing the element clicked. Also, you should not use the same id attribute for multiple elements (since you specify a static id within a loop). Instead of using the HTML attribute `onclick`, it would be easier to setup with pure jQuery. Assuming that only the buttons with class `"btn-sh-grey"` are desired, you can do something like:

```
$.each($('.btn-sh-grey'), function(index, elem) {
  $(this).click(function(event) {
    $('.faq-tog').removeClass('active').addClass('invisible');
    $(this).find('.faq-tog').removeClass('invisible').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! Still can't get it working, but I understood the `this` issue and, about the ids, I used to use them for css purposes, just like classes, before I knew it's not a good thing haha

Answer (score 1):

without code its hard to check:

```
$('tog-faq').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('togglingClass');
});
```

this code toggles the class of the .tog-faq element if its clicked

Comment: sorry I hit enter before i finished ç_ç